# Electron shell.openExternal can't open some .lnk shortcuts

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm creating a launcher using electron. It launches applications and files in my Windows system using the shell.openExternal command.

It works well when I call shell.openExternal passing .lnk shortcuts as parameters, but when I call some apparently equal shortcuts created by, for example, GoG installers, the game is not launched and I can't debug what happens. I know that the shortcut is called but the target application crashes. I got this message from Lichdom: Battlemage launcher:

[image]

Witcher 3 also fails, nos message is displayed. When I call these shortcuts directly from the system, they work fine. If I manually create an apparently exact same shortcut to the same file, it launches normally in both electron and the explorer.

Any ideas what could be happening or how to debug?